# Count string length but exclude some characters

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to take in string input and count them but exclude certain characters but it seems to be counting all the characters no matter what I do.

```
user_text = input()

count = 0

for i in user_text:
    if i in user_text != 'a':
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: `print(sum(i != 'a' for i in input()))`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `i` is not equal to `a`

```
if i != 'a':
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with just

```
if i != 'a':
```

Answer (score 0):

More "pythonic" way could be:

```
user_text = input()

count = len([True for x in user_text if x != 'a'])

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is [chaining comparison operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/) which is not what you want. Because your statement is the same as:

```py
(i in user_text) and (user_text != 'a')
```

The first statement is always True, because you iterate over every character in `user_text`.
The second statement is only False, when the `user_text` is `a`. You can try this by entering an `a` as input.

So to achieve what you want, you should use this statement as in other answers already suggested:

```py
if i != 'a'
```

Small side note: It could help your understanding when you rename `i` to something like `char`, because `i` is most often used in for-loops that count from 0 to n. e.g. `fo i in range(10)`